# How can I popd to a specific directory?

Tags: bash, pushd

I have used `pushd` to move about to various directories and now if I run

```
dirs -v
```

I get:

```
 0  ~/Desktop
 1  /etc
 2  /var/log
 3  ~/Downloads
 4  /tmp
```

How can I `popd` to a specific directory in the middle of the stack?, e.g `option 2: /var/log`

`man bash` says

> +n     Removes the nth entry counting from the left of the list shown
>   by dirs, starting with zero.  For example: ``popd +0'' removes the
>   first directory, ``popd +1'' the second.

I've tried

- ``popd +0''
- popd +3

And it pops the correct directory off the stack, but doesn't change the current working directory.

How can I `popd` the particular directory and change the current working directory to the "popped" dir?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cd "`dirs +<number>`"
```

where `<number>` is 0 or 3 or something else.

In any case, I recommend you check out a cd wrapper such as 
http://davidcorne.com/tag/cd/ , which `push`es onto the dir stack in the background and allows you to do `cd --` instead of `dirs -v` and `cd -<number>` to get you into the directory you want. It also replaces initial tildas with `$HOME`, eliminating the problem you've alluded to in the comments.

Comment: Interesting. The above does work for me. Well, at least it seems you're close as it does try to get you to `/var/log` which, indeed, is the #2-indexed entry in your dir stack.

Comment: yes funny, am I supposed to type with the double quotes and back-ticks? if so, do you know why quotes are necessary?

Comment: You can experiment with removing the quotes but they should be there for the sake of robustness in case you ever pushd a dir that has a space in its path.

Comment: makes sense, My problem seems that when `dirs +<number>` is executed and the value it returned includes a `~` in the path (i.e. any directory in /home) the `cd` command wont accept it. as normally the `~` tilde expansion would be performed prior to the `cd` running

Comment: See my edit. If the super cd script doesn't suit you, you can extract the `~` tilda replacement part and put it into a differently named bash function.

Comment: thanks, this didnt answer my question directly but pointed me in the right direction enough, when I researched extracting tilda I found (by blind luck) [this  article on tilde expansion](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/bash-tilde-expansion/) which contained an example for changing dirs. turns out `cd ~+<number>` e.g. `cd ~+2` works nicely when the dir you want to switch to a directory that contains `~`

Answer (score 0):

I found the script in the .bashrc file in the Cygwin distribution.  It did not work properly because in line 20

```
adir=$(dirs +$index)
```

adir now includes the index, e.g., ' 2  /cygdrive/d' so I added a line thereafter

```
adir=${adir:4}
```

and it seems to work